# How to return the result in async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, return, task

I want to return the value of async Task as string, When I implement it error occurs with the error message System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace USCInventoryService.CLASS
{
    public static class RestFulHelper
    {
        private static readonly string baseURL = Properties.Settings.Default.Uri;

        public static string BeautifyJson(string jsonStr)
        {
            JToken parseJson = JToken.Parse(jsonStr);
            return parseJson.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
        }

        public static async Task<string> PostRFID(string token, string RFID, string status)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
            var inputData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"token",token },
                {"RFID",RFID },
                {"status", status}
            };

            var input = new FormUrlEncodedContent(inputData);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + "transaction/api", input))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                    {
                        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
}

Call in Service.asmx

    [WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> PostChkAccessPoint(string _token, string _RFID, string _status)
    {
        var response = await CLASS.RestFulHelper.PostRFID(_token, _RFID, _status);
        string _res = CLASS.RestFulHelper.BeautifyJson(response);
        return await Task.FromResult(_res);
    }
```

Comment: You're already returning the result correctly, and awaiting it correctly; I *suspect* the exception is coming from something not specific to the actual returning of the string; if you run it in a debugger, where does it explode?

Comment: error happened to this line: using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + "transaction/api", input))

Comment: "error happened to this line" - great; now debug that; what part is `null`? presumably not `client`, but what about `input`?

Comment: the input is not null

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try this

```
....

var formFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("token",token)),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("RFID",RFID )),
         new KeyValuePair<string,string>("status", status));

        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formFields);


using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
               var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + "/transaction/api", formContent ))
               
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await response.content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                       
                    }
               
            }
```

or you can try:

```
 var formFields  = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
     {"token",token },
                {"RFID",RFID },
                {"status", status}
            };

   
   var formContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formFields), UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

and this

```
[WebMethod]
 public async Task<string> PostChkAccessPoint(string _token, string _RFID, string _status)
    {
   var responseString = await CLASS.RestFulHelper.PostRFID(_token, _RFID, _status);

       return CLASS.RestFulHelper.BeautifyJson(responseString);
}
```

Comment: The same error,  An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you use a debugger and define where this error happens?

Comment: Error happened in this line: var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + "/transaction/api", input);

Comment: Did you check baseurl value and input value?

Comment: Yes the baseurl is good no problem on that line. When I execute as async void I had no problem, but I want to return the result as string

Comment: When I use this code: [WebMethod]
        public async void PostCheckPoint(string _token, string _RFID, string _status)
        {
            string response = await CLASS.RestFulHelper.PostRFID(_token, _RFID, _status);
            string _res = CLASS.RestFulHelper.BeautifyJson(response);
            Result = _res;

        } No error but of course no return value

Comment: Response  can't be null. It is somewhere inside.